# How does the following line of code work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I am currently following along with a react/redux tutorial that has me using ES6 and immutable.js both of which I am new to.

In the following function:

```
export function vote(state, entry) {
  return state.updateIn(
    ['vote', 'tally', entry],
    0,
    tally => tally + 1
  );
}
```

This line: `tally => tally + 1` Has me a bit confused.

Is this a feature of ES6 or immutable? I understand that the result of this function will be that the current value of `tally` will be incremented by 1, but the syntax is unusual to me.

In the immutable docs this line is referred to as the `updater`, but i don't not see a description of it and I do not understand if it is then a feature of ES6 itself. If it is whats another example of this being used and whats a non ES6 example?

I am sorry if this is a bit confusing I am not sure how else to word this question.

By the way the state map looks like this:

```
const state = Map({
  vote: Map({
    pair: List.of('Trainspotting', '28 Days Later'),
    tally: Map({
      'Trainspotting': 3,
      '28 Days Later': 2
    })
  }),
```

Comment: @Gothdo: yep, that answer is much better than mine. I'll keep the link for the next time I see this question. :)

Comment: Not sure if this is the same thing I know that in ES6 => can be used as a function expression "arrow notation" they call it right? But in this case tally is not a function? So tally some how being called as a function anyway? That's what's confusing me because it looks like it's calling a function called tally but I don't have a function called tally?

Comment: Oh wait I think I understand now.... It's a function that's taking tally as input and return tally plus 1 .... I see now!

Comment: Yep, it's an anonymous function, taking one argument (which is named `tally`)

Comment: I didn't realize you didn't need the parenthesis

Comment: Note that the parentheses can *only* be omitted when the arrow function has exactly one argument.